# Required_If Combination Issue in github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 package

Tags: go, struct, slice, go-gorm, delve

**Package version eg. v9, v10:**

**Package Version: v10**

Issue, Question or Enhancement:
When I trying to run the below code. i get this error this is wired

**Output**

```
Validation error: Key: 'Application.Applicants[0].Entity.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[0].Entity.TaxID' Error:Field validation for 'TaxID' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[1].Person.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[1].Person.Age' Error:Field validation for 'Age' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[1].Person.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'required' tag
```

***Code sample, to showcase or reproduce:***

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type Application struct {
    Applicants []Applicant `validate:"dive"`
}

type Applicant struct {
    ApplicantCategory string `validate:"required,oneof=PERSON ENTITY"`
    Person            Person `validate:"required_if=ApplicantCategory PERSON"`
    Entity            Entity `validate:"required_if=ApplicantCategory ENTITY"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name  string `validate:"required"`
    Age   int    `validate:"required,gte=18"`
    Email string `validate:"required,email"`
}

type Entity struct {
    Name  string `validate:"required"`
    TaxID string `validate:"required"`
}

func main() {
    // Create a new validator instance
    v := validator.New()

    // Create an instance of Application to validate
    data := Application{
        Applicants: []Applicant{
            {
                ApplicantCategory: "PERSON",
                Person: Person{
                    Name:  "John Doe",
                    Age:   25,
                    Email: "john@example.com",
                },
            },
            {
                ApplicantCategory: "ENTITY",
                Entity: Entity{
                    Name:  "Example Corp",
                    TaxID: "123456789",
                },
            },
        },
    }

    // Use the validator to validate the Application struct and its Applicants
    if err := v.Struct(data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Validation error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Validation passed")
    }
}
```

Could not find out what is the issue in the code or validator package. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`omitempty`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Omit_Empty) e.g.:

```
type Applicant struct {
    ApplicantCategory string `validate:"required,oneof=PERSON ENTITY"`
    Person            Person `validate:"required_if=ApplicantCategory PERSON,omitempty"`
    Entity            Entity `validate:"required_if=ApplicantCategory ENTITY,omitempty"`
}
```

Full example in [playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/FWRj943M8dL) (note that this dos not run reliably in the playground due to the size of imported packages).

The issue is that the `required_if` causes the library to check if the `Person`/`Entity` is present, but the library will still validate the empty `Person`/`Entity` (and that fails!).  Adding `omitempty` means that the library will ignore an empty `struct`; this provides the desired result because the `required_if` will ensure that any required `struct` is not empty (meaning it will be validated).

An alternative option is to use pointers ([playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/EXQn4Rcqhxm)):

```
type Applicant struct {
    ApplicantCategory string `validate:"required,oneof=PERSON ENTITY"`
    Person            *Person `validate:"required_if=ApplicantCategory PERSON"`
    Entity            *Entity `validate:"required_if=ApplicantCategory ENTITY"`
}
```

The difference here is that when there is no `Entity` then the value will be `nil` (as opposed to a `Entity` with default values) meaning there is nothing for `validator` to validate.

Nots: I'd suggest using `v := validator.New(validator.WithRequiredStructEnabled())` (as per [the docs](https://github.com/go-playground/validator#special-notes)).

Comment: @Britis Can you explain why we are using a pointer here and how it works??

omitempty is not not working for me it still throws the validation error

Comment: Validation error: Key: 'Application.Applicants[0].Entity.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[0].Entity.TaxID' Error:Field validation for 'TaxID' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[1].Person.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[1].Person.Age' Error:Field validation for 'Age' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'Application.Applicants[1].Person.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'required' tag

this error after adding omitempty

Comment: Sorry - I can't duplicate this. I've added playground links so you can run my full example (you will probably need to copy the code to your local machine to run it).